# parametric line renders a mesh: how functions are parsed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the code below I define three functions `u(x, y)`, `v(x, y)` and `w(x, y)` which just define a simple parameterization of the unit sphere

```
u(x, y) = sin(x) * cos(y)
v(x, y) = sin(x) * sin(y)
w(x, y) = cos(x)
```

I proceed to plot three different sets: **1**: The whole surface of the sphere. **2** Points for which azimuthal angle is zero `y = 0`. **3** Same as 2, but explicitly changing the functions

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain            = 0 : 180,
  y domain          = 0 : 360,
  declare function  = {
    u(\x, \y) = sin(\x) * cos(\y);
    v(\x, \y) = sin(\x) * sin(\y);
    w(\x, \y) = cos(\x);
  }
  ]

  % 1. sphere
  \addplot3 [surf, opacity = 0.1] ({u(\x, \y)}, {v(\x, \y)}, {w(\x, \y)});

  % 2. y = 0
  \addplot3 [red, opacity = 1] ({u(\x, 0)}, {v(\x, 0)}, {w(\x, 0)});

  % 3. same as before?
  \addplot3 [blue, samples y = 0, opacity = 1] ({sin(\x) * cos(0)}, {sin(\x) * sin(0)}, {cos(\x)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I was expecting to see a single red line (the second set), instead I see the whole mesh again. But If I explicitly set `y = 0` in the function (blue line) it works. Why is that? I assume it has to do with the way functions are parsed, but that's about it ... no idea what's happening

Comment: @marmot I forgot to mention, if I explicitly say `samples y = 0` I get an error `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex
pected to sample a line, not a mesh (...)`

Comment: I am wondering if this should be mentioned to the `pgfplots` developer. After all the error message here is not necessarily illuminating. If it had `Do you have excess spaces in you function declarations?` in addition this may help to avoid some fair amount of headache.

Comment: @marmot Probably should, this was very frustrating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OMG! Spaces! All you need to do is to remove the spaces before `\y` inside `declare function`. That is, `u(\x, \y) = sin(\x) * cos(\y);` has to become `u(\x,\y) = sin(\x) * cos(\y);` and so on.   (@egreg, where are you. why didn't you see this? ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain            = 0 : 180,
  y domain          = 0 : 360,
  declare function  = {
    u(\x,\y) = sin(\x) * cos(\y);
    v(\x,\y) = sin(\x) * sin(\y);
    w(\x,\y) = cos(\x);
  }
  ]

  % 1. sphere
  \addplot3 [surf, opacity = 0.1] ({u(\x, \y)}, {v(\x, \y)}, {w(\x, \y)});

  % 2. y = 0
  \addplot3 [red, opacity = 1] ({u(\x, 0)}, {v(\x, 0)}, {w(\x, 0)});

  % 3. same as before?
  %\addplot3 [blue, samples y = 0, opacity = 1] ({sin(\x) * cos(0)}, {sin(\x) * sin(0)}, {cos(\x)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yes, I know that the plot is closed, but this is not the point here. You could do

```
 \addplot3 [mesh,color=red,samples y=0, opacity = 1] ({u(\x, 0)}, {v(\x, 0)}, {w(\x, 0)});
```

instead.

[image]

Comment: lol ... another cruel reminder this is a text processor :)

Comment: @caverac I didn't know this. Ironically, you can have spaces like crazy in `\addplot3 [surf, opacity = 0.1] ({u(\x, \y)}, {v(\x, \y)}, {w(\x, \y)});`.