# Pgfplots, declare function and evaluation of parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I just want to plot a function with some parameters which I want to be arguments of the function
Referring to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124878/declare-function-for-tikzpicture) I made my own code with my own function, but when I try to compile it says `Undefined control sequence`. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            declare function={VMorse(\x, \De, \aval, \xre) = \De*(exp(-2*\aval*(\x-\xre))- 2*exp(-\aval*(\x-\xre)));},%
        ]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[domain=1:5] {VMorse(x, 2, 1, 0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

White spaces! Do not use them in the arguments of the function

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            declare function={VMorse(\x,\De,\aval,\xre)=\De*(exp(-2*\aval*(\x-\xre))- 2*exp(-\aval*(\x-\xre)));},%
        ]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[domain=1:5] {VMorse(x, 2, 1, 0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

@[marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) actually found this to be the solution in a previous question of mine

[parametric line renders a mesh: how functions are parsed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469153/parametric-line-renders-a-mesh-how-functions-are-parsed)

Comment: Nice! Didn't expect it all, tikz manual should emphasise this peculiarity...