# Transforming the second argument to a TikZ function doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a 2 input function I want to plot:

```
declare function = {
    func(\x, \y) = sqrt(\x^2 + \y^2);
}
```

I want to transform the function one down. Hence when I call it in my TikZ plot I do:

```
func(x, y + 1)
```

Expecting to see:

[image]

However instead I get

[image]

Doing the same with the x coordinates works:

```
func(x + 1, y)
```

[image]

Hence I ask why applying transformations doesn't work with the second variable (`y` in this case)?

The full code is as follows, and I'm using overleaf (pdflatex is the default setting):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 6cm, height = 6cm, compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        func(\x, \y) = sqrt(\x^2 + \y^2);
    }
]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = \(x\),
        ylabel = \(y\),
        view={0}{90},
    ]
    \addplot3[
        shader = interp,
        domain = -1:1,
        domain y = -1:1,
        samples = 50,
        samples y = 50,
        surf]{func(x, y + 1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469254